# Custom Single-Sign-On with ASP.NET Identity 2.0 and MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I am re-writing my MVC 4 forms authentication app in MVC 5 with Identity 2.0.

Currently, the site is using a proprietary single-sign-on method that decrypts an incoming parameter from a POST request, and based on the validity of the contents, it uses FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie to set the authentication cookie and redirects the user to the secured content.

Now that I am using ASP.Net Identity, what is the appropriate replacement for the FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie functionality?  Keep in mind, I don't want to have to persist any of these users to a database.  They should just exist inside their tokens/cookies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it!
I found the solution in [this helpful article](http://brockallen.com/2013/10/24/a-primer-on-owin-cookie-authentication-middleware-for-the-asp-net-developer/).

Basically, you create a ClaimsIdentity and then use the AuthenticationManager from the OWINContext to "SignIn" the identity and that creates the authentication cookie.

Like this:

```
var claims = new List<Claim>();
claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Brock"));
claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, "brockallen@gmail.com"));
var id = new ClaimsIdentity(claims,DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

var ctx = Request.GetOwinContext();
var authenticationManager = ctx.Authentication;
authenticationManager.SignIn(id);
```